# Is there any vim plugin provides brackets jump features?

Tags: vim

I am looking for a vim plugin which can provide the following functions:

1. automatically let the cursor jump one character ahead and insert a tag(<++>) at the original place if the user input a pair of brackets with nothing between them.
2. when user press ctrl+j, the cursor jumps to the next <++> and remove the tag, as well as push user into insert mode.

I have seen these kind of features in vim-latexsuit. But, I cannot use it while I am not writing tex files.

So, if it possible to find some vim plugins which can provide these functions?

I will appreciate it if anyone can give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
" A syntax for placeholders
" Pressing Control-j jumps to the next match.
inoremap <c-j> <Esc>/<++><CR><Esc>cf>
" Completions using placeholders
inoremap ) )<++><Esc>F)i
inoremap ] ]<++><Esc>F]i
inoremap } }<++><Esc>F}i
```

Add those it your .vimrc
It should work